# Qual evento jQuery usar para fazer consulta no banco de dados?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, sql

```
jQuery(function($){

    // Chamando as funções
    $('#busca-cidades').keyup(function(){ ...
```

Estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados e retornando esta consulta formatada com html/css e a consulta é em SQL do WordPress. Até ai nada de muito diferente. O problema é que quando eu faço a consulta com o evento `keyup` a cada letra que eu digito faz-se uma consulta e além disso, a página ainda fica piscando como se tivesse dando `refresh`.

Qual evento eu poderia usar para que fizesse a consulta só quando eu terminasse de digitar a palavra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irá ter que adivinhar sempre quando o user acaba de escrever. para isso vamos assumir 5 segundos.

```
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 5000; // 5 segundos 


$('#busca-cidades').keyup(function(){
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
if ($('#busca-cidades').val) {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
}
});

function doneTyping () {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Terá de fazer uma query ajax e ir buscar os dados atravez de um ficheiro server side, ler depois através do success function onde terá acesso aos dados que Vêm do ficheiro php /asp lendo os mesmos em json.